# How to show another window

Tags: python, pyqt5

The  project occurs loging in and signing in.

Im trying a  transition from registerwindow to mainwindow and when we submit the window is automatically transit to mainwindow. There is only way to do this (at least for me) i have to import two python doc which named  mainwindow.py and register.py, they are in same doc by the way.

This is the mainmenu.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtGui,QtWidgets

from window.register import Ui_Form

class Ui_MainWindow(object):


def login(self):

    self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.ui = Ui_Form()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()
    MainWindow.hide()
```

and this is register.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from window.mainmenu import Ui_MainWindow

import sqlite3

class Ui_Form(object):
def submit(self):
    sorgu2 = "Select * From users where nickname = ?"
    sorgu = "INSERT INTO users values(?,?)"
    self.cursor.execute(sorgu,(self.lineEdit.text(),self.lineEdit.text()))
    self.connect.commit()
    Form.hide()
    self.window2 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui2 = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui2.setupUi(self.window2)
    self.window2.show()
```

Its supposed to be when i clicked to the button the register window will be hidden and mainmenu window will be show. Same thing for the mainmenu but the direct opposite

I know i am doing circular dependent imports but there is no other way but importing them to each other

Comment: in another file you could create loop which creates first window and when you exit first window the it destroy it and create second window. When you close second window then it go to beginning of loop and shows first window.

Comment: Or main window should hide itself (not destroy), and show second window. When second window end it job then it should close it and then code should go back to main window, which should destroy second window and show again main window. Second window shouldn't create first window but it should exit to go back to main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If second window will be `QDialog` then you can hide main window, use `exec()` for `QDialog` and main window will wait till you close `QDialog`, and when it returns to main window then you can show it again.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show Second Window", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_second_window)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def show_second_window(self):
        self.hide() # hide main window

        self.second = SecondWindow()
        self.second.exec() # will wait till you close second window

        self.show() # show main window again


class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog): # it has to be dialog

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close It", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_second_window)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def show_second_window(self):
        self.close() # go back to main window


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

---

The other popular method is to create two widgets with all contents and replace widgets in one window.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show Second Window", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_second_window)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def show_second_window(self):
        self.close()
        self.parent.set_content("Second")


class SecondWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Close It", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.show_second_window)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.show()

    def show_second_window(self):
        self.close()
        self.parent.set_content("Main")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.set_content("Main")

        self.show()

    def set_content(self, new_content):
        if new_content == "Main":
            self.content = MainWidget(self)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        elif new_content == "Second":           
            self.content = SecondWidget(self)
            self.layout.addWidget(self.content)



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

---

**EDIT:** Change window's content using `QStackedLayout`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class FirstWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show Second Stack", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.change_stack)

        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def change_stack(self):
        self.parent().stack.setCurrentIndex(1)


class SecondWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Show First Stack", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.change_stack)

        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def change_stack(self):
        self.parent().stack.setCurrentIndex(0)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.stack = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout(self)

        self.stack1 = FirstWidget(self)
        self.stack2 = SecondWidget(self)

        self.stack.addWidget(self.stack1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.stack2)

        self.show()



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Why did we used  self.parent = parent and what is self.parent.set_content("Second") for.

Comment: and one more question in this line app = QtWidgets.QApplication([]) why there is a '[]'

Comment: You can run script in console with arguments - `python script.py arg1 arg2` which you will have as list `sys.argv` and you can send it to `QApplication(sys.argv)`. This way you change some settings in Qt module when you start script. As I remeber this way you can change theme used by Qt. But I don't need these arguments so I put empty list instead of `sys.argv`. I can't use `QApplication()`  without any list because it would display error.

Comment: in second example I have only one window and I change widget inside this window. I have function `set_content` in MainWindow to do this. I send `parent` to widgets so they have access to main window and to `set_content` and they can run it to change content when i press button in widget.

Comment: is there set_content() function in python? or it is belongs to pyqt5? 

and when we do this -self.parent.set_content("Main")-  is self.parent equalling to 'Main', and set_content('Main') which belongs to MainWindow how did you convert it. I really dont understand :(

Comment: better see again code in second example. `set_content()` is not part of Python nor PyQt. I created `set_content()` in `MainWindow`. And self.parent is instance of `MainWindow` which I send as parameter `self` in `MainWidget(self)` and `SecondWidet(self)`. And inside this function is `if` which compares strings `new_content == "Main"` and when string in `new_content` is `"Main"` then it put widget `MainWidget` in window. You can always use print to see what you have in variables - ie. `print(new_content, type(new_content), dir(new_content))`. It helps to understand code.

Comment: There is a 3rd method which is using Stackable Widgets which would resemble the 2nd method you posted with only a few changes that might make it more nimble

Comment: @DennisJensen thank you for information. In 2nd method I used experience from `tkinter` but I expected that Qt may have widget for this. Later I will create example with Stackable Widgets.