# in PyQt moving between screen when pressing a button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm building restaurant app for practice with PyQt5 i have 2 problems:
I have a main screen that will take the user to other screens

1. when changing between screens in the second time i get error and it crash
2. The previous window won't close when i'm moving to the new window so every time it's new window

I tried searching for information about it and all i can find is how to do things in the same screen not in a new screen

Code for you to see yourself:

first screen:

```
from mainMenu import*
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets    
mod=0#0 - TA , 1- Delivery
class Ui_Main():
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1072, 747)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.ta = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ta.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 50, 191, 171))
        self.ta.setObjectName("ta")
        self.ta.clicked.connect(self.taClicked)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1072, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMain = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMain.setObjectName("menuMain")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMain.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", 
       "MainWindow"))

        self.ta.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TA"))
        self.menuMain.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main"))

    def taClicked(self):
        mod=0
        print("here")
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainMenu()  # ------------->creating an object
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Main()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second screen:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from main import*

class Ui_MainMenu(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1073, 738)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(685, 40, 331, 251))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 330, 561, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 385, 71, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 440, 81, 51))
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 380, 81, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(727, 370, 61, 41))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")

        self.pushButton_40 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_40.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 600, 141, 41))
        self.pushButton_40.setObjectName("pushButton_40")
        self.pushButton_40.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1073, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainMenu", "MainMenu"))

        self.pushButton_40.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))

    def btnclicked(self):
        print("here")
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.m= Ui_Main()
        self.m.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainMenu()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adir/PycharmProjects/main.py", line 61, in taClicked
    self.ui = Ui_MainMenu()  # ------------->creating an object
NameError: name 'Ui_MainMenu' is not defined
```

Comment: maybe you should create two widgets with different content and replace them in one window. OR use stacked layout manager to keep both screens in one window. See QStackedLayout in last example in [How to show another window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57657174/1832058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
#from mainMenu import*
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets   

mod = 0    #0 - TA , 1- Delivery


class Ui_MainMenu(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1073, 738)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(685, 40, 331, 251))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 330, 561, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 385, 71, 41))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 440, 81, 51))
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 380, 81, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(727, 370, 61, 41))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")

        self.pushButton_40 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_40.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 600, 141, 41))
        self.pushButton_40.setObjectName("pushButton_40")
#        self.pushButton_40.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1073, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainMenu", "MainMenu"))

        self.pushButton_40.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))


class Ui_Main():
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1072, 747)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.ta = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.ta.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 50, 191, 171))
        self.ta.setObjectName("ta")
#        self.ta.clicked.connect(self.taClicked)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1072, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuMain = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuMain.setObjectName("menuMain")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuMain.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", 
       "MainWindow"))

        self.ta.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TA"))
        self.menuMain.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Main"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ta.clicked.connect(self.taClicked)

    def taClicked(self):
        mod = 0
        print("here")

        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.mainMenu = Ui_MainMenu()                                # ------------->creating an object
        self.mainMenu.setupUi(self.window)
        self.mainMenu.pushButton_40.clicked.connect(self.btnclicked)

        self.window.show()
        self.hide()

    def btnclicked(self):
        self.window.hide()
        self.show()        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_Main()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```